# How do I turn my shell module command into my own module in ansible using bash?

Tags: bash, shell, module, ansible

This is my yml file:

```
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    www_port: 80
  become: yes
  tasks:
   - name: install lsof if it's redhat
     yum:
       name: lsof
       state: latest
     when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'
   - name: install lsof if  it's debian
     apt:
       name: lsof
       state: latest
     when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' or ansible_distribution == 'Debian'

   - name: Finding out what web server it uses
     shell: "lsof -i :{{ www_port }} | grep LISTEN | cut -d ' ' -f 1"
     register: result
   - name: output the result of what web server it uses
     debug: msg="{{ result.stdout_lines|first }}"

   - name: list all vhosts if it uses httpd
     shell: cd /etc/httpd/sites-enabled; ls | while read file; do awk '/^ServerName/ {f=1} f {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$
     register: rezult
     when: result.stdout_lines|first == "httpd"
   - name: output vhosts rezult if it uses httpd
     debug: msg="{{ rezult.stdout_lines }}"
     when: result.stdout_lines|first == "httpd"

   - name: list all vhosts if it uses nginx
     shell: cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled; ls | while read file; do awk '/^server_name/ {f=1} f {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++$
     register: recult
     when: result.stdout_lines|first == "nginx"
   - name: output vhosts recult (results) if it uses nginx
     debug: msg="{{ recult.stdout_lines }}"
     when: result.stdout_lines|first == "nginx"
```

I want to turn these "shell:" module commands into my own module using a bash script since I don't know python. Essentially this playbook outputs the name of the webserver the host uses and it outputs all the vhosts in the the webserver configuration file. I want to combine these shell: module commands into one module that does all of those things.

ansible.cfg file states that the library of my own modules are in /usr/share/my_modules so I made that directory and made a vhosts.bash script that is basically the second shell command in the yml file. I replaced that line ("shell: ....") with ony "vhosts:" but that didn't work.
This is the vhosts.bash file in /usr/share/my_modules

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /etc/httpd/sites-enabled;
ls | while read file;
do awk '/^ServerName/ {f=1} f {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/\./) print $i; else if($i!="ServerName") exit}' $file;
done;
```

and when I run the playbook I get:

```
  - name: list all vhosts if it uses httpd
     ^ here
```

but it has nothing to do with the name, this is the line in the yml:

```
- name: list all vhosts if it uses httpd
     vhosts:
     register: rezult
```

I don't know if I completly missed the point but that's kind of how this guy did it in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=aY7lmtW8ROM

Comment: Can you also please include the error you are receiving, the contents of the bash script, and the output from `ansible-config dump |grep DEFAULT_MODULE_PATH` (run in the same folder you are running `ansible-playbook` from)?

Comment: I edited. As for the module path this is the output 
```
(default) = [u'/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
```

Comment: do you really mean to `rezult`, `recult` as well as `result` ? (Hmm, making each section unique?) . Also, did  you try `/full/path/to/myScript` ? Good luck.

Comment: Yes, it's a different variable, so I changed the name a little bit. Changing the path didn't work, but thank you.

Comment: Did you miss a quotes after the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are picking up the default module paths:

```
(default) = ['/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
```

You will need to either move your module, change the global ansible.cfg, or create a local ansible.cfg. If the module is specific to this playbook, you can also consider just placing it in a folder called `library` in the playbook directory.

The second issue you will run into is that your bash module needs to output the success/failure status in a way that is readable by Ansible. As an example, you would need to have output similar to:

```
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  printf '{"changed": true, "rc": 0}'
else
  printf '{"failed": true, "msg": "Something went wrong", "rc": 1}'
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I just removed the comment from the path and it recognized my module. But I'm not sure what you mean by conditional, I had an error for my module. It sort of recognizes the output that I want but it claims error. Usually the vhosts are in order one after the other in the debug msg. I will send the eror in the next comment

Comment: "module_stdout": "www.site1.com\r\nsite3.com\r\ndomain.site4\r\ndomain65-something.dom\r\ndasad.sdsd\r\nwww.site2.com\r\nkorosion.fg\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 0

Comment: I also ran it with the conditional statment you sent me and it just changed the error into something like  "The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute ".

Comment: I think you will need to remove the `print` and `exit` parts of your script so that you can deal with return values properly at the end. Try assigning your output in the bash script to a variable, like `RESULT`, and then returning that in the json structure. Something like `printf '{"changed": true, "rc": 0, "stdout": '"\"${RESULT}\""'}'`  <-- the quote escaping is a little awkward but I think that's the price you pay for using bash over python. You may have better luck with `echo` rather than `printf`

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these work. I'll ask another question with a more ismpler shell module conversion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your indentation is right, the line after name should be in line like:

`- name: list all vhosts if it uses httpd
  vhosts:`

Comment: Yes, I know. It is like that.